# .map is not a function React

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, reactjs, jsx

I'm working on a small app that will pull some data from a JSON file (game scores). Currently I am getting the error, `games.map is not a function`. I saw another post on Stack Overflow that was similar, but the answer was that the initial state was not an array, but I have set my initial state to be an array, so I don't believe it applies. Below is my React JS can anyone point me in the right direction? Could it have something to do with the JSON structure? You can find the json file [here](http://pinetar-app.com/src/client/app/mlb-scoreboard.json). Thank you kindly!

```
class SingleGame extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div>{this.props.homeTeam}</div>
    );
  }
}

class GameBox extends React.Component{

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      games: []
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this._getGameScores();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._timer = setInterval(() => this._getGameScores(), 45000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this._timer);
  }

  _getGameScores(){
    jQuery.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://pinetar-app.com/src/client/app/mlb-scoreboard.json',
      success: function(games){
        this.setState({games: games.data});
      }.bind(this)
    });
  }

  _mapGameScores(){
    const games = this.state.games;

    return games.map((games) => {
      return(
        <SingleGame homeTeam={games.game.home_team_name} />
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    const gameList = this._mapGameScores();
    return(
      <div>
      {gameList}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <GameBox />, document.getElementById('pinetar')
);
```

Comment: can you log games before you return it in?

Comment: `data` seems to be a object, not an array

Comment: Yes, and it looks like it returns an `object` and then inside that is an Array of games that are objects. So I guess the questions now becomes how do I access these objects? You can see a `console.log` screenshot here: http://prnt.sc/b175rh  @JordanHendrix

Comment: yea you're not getting the games array...see answer below:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't accessing the array properly, try using mapping over this:

```
data.data.games.game
```

like so:

[Working example](https://jsbin.com/bemagul/2/edit?js,console)

```
_getGameScores(){
    jQuery.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://pinetar-app.com/src/client/app/mlb-scoreboard.json',
      success: function(data){
        this.setState({games: data.data.games.game });
      }.bind(this)
    });
  }
```

Comment: You sir, just made my weekend. I'm still learning react so I appreciate you taking your time to help out. Cheers!

Comment: any time! we've all been there happy to help!